# How to integrate the xbl wizard component in properties-local.xml or properties form-runner.xml?

Tags: properties, wizard, orbeon, xbl

I want to add a class css 'visited' to wizard-toc so i modified in **wizard.xbl** with this expression

```
<xh:li class="{{
    'has-errors' [$top-level-section-has-any-errors],
    'invalid'    [$top-level-section-has-visible-errors],
    'incomplete' [$top-level-section-incomplete],
    'not-started'[$top-level-section-not-started],

    'disabled'   [$top-level-section-disabled],
    'active'     [$top-level-section-active],
    'visited'     [$top-level-section-visited],

}}">
```

and in **wizard.css**

```
.orbeon .xbl-fr-wizard .fr-wizard-toc .nav .visited> span > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffaa48;
}
```

so where can I declare the directory **/xbl/wizard** in properties files and which **property** I will use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your modified file under:

```
WEB-INF/resources/xbl/orbeon/wizard/wizard.xbl
```

But be very careful: if you upgrade Orbeon Forms, you will have to merge changes with the newer version of `wizard.xbl`.